# Using Bootstrap, but Text not Responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a school project : http://lauralynn87.github.io/WSP/Project/index.html

and I am using the framework Bootstrap 3.0 - and almost everything is responsive, but the text.

I've tried using percentages and ems for font sizes..but nothing is working. I know I'm missing something, but can't figure it out.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 28):

Fonts are not responsive if you use `%` or `em` etc.

If you want to change the size of your font on different screen/window sizes, you have to use media queries in CSS.

For example:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) { /* screen size until 1200px */
    body {
        font-size: 1.5em; /* 1.5x default size */
    }
}
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) { /* screen size until 1000px */
    body {
        font-size: 1.2em; /* 1.2x default size */
        }
    }
@media all and (max-width: 500px) { /* screen size until 500px */
    body {
        font-size: 0.8em; /* 0.8x default size */
        }
    }
```

The numbers are of course only examples.

Comment: Okay...I guess I assumed Bootstrap took care of the media queries. I'll try this though. Thanks.

Comment: @user2800027 Bootstrap takes care of media queries, but not for fonts, because it's unusual to change the font using media queries. Normally the font size doesn't adjust the screen/window size, but of course it's possible.

Comment: Yea - it's not working. I tried the media queiries and the text still won't respond.

Comment: @user2800027 Where did you add the media queries? I can't find them in your link

Comment: Bootstraps font sizes do not change for different media queries. I have no idea why that decision was made like that. Makes sense for a smaller screen to have smaller text than a large screen.

Answer (score 26):

Here is a mobile first css snippet for screen only using Bootstrap device sizes.
Comments:

- Bootstrap does not scale typography in response to display size changes.
- Do you really want the same font size on a 27" monitor as a smart phone? I see several good designs where different font sizes for different screens make sense. Testing will prove your design right or wrong.
- Do you really want screen and print font sizes to be the same? Screen and print are different beasts. If you care about printing, you should test it separately.
- The font scaling I use below is arbitrary - no magic there.

.

```
/* xs < 768 */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    body {
        font-size: 0.9em;
    }
}

/* sm */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1em;
    }
}

/* md */
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1.2em;
    }
}

/* lg */
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    body {
        font-size: 1.3em;
    }
}
```

A jsfiddle that shows the effects: https://jsfiddle.net/stevetarver/9a8ym3hL/embedded/result/. Note that the media queries are only changing th, td font sizes, not body as shown above.

Comment: Thank you. This is fantastic with the perfect jsfiddle to demonstrate it.

Comment: For clarity, the above scheme declares tablet portrait (>768) as the target platform and scales up/down for the other platforms. Mobile first would use 1.0em on <768 and scale up for other platforms. In practice, you have to play with the sizes and figure out what works best for the css you include.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest `Fittext jQuery plugin` to make all the text responsive by default. It requires only 2 js files and a single line of jQuery code.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fittext.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
          $("body").fitText();
  });
</script>
```

Refer [Fittext](http://fittextjs.com/)

Comment: The plugin itself discourages using it for all body text. 

"Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!"

Answer (score 5):

you can use Viewport Sized Typography.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 5.9vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 3.0vh;
}
p {
  font-size: 2vmin;
}
```

the text size changes according to the view port (browser's width and height).

more details https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography

**Demo** : https://css-tricks.com/examples/ViewportTypography/

Answer (score 0):

add your own media queries to change the font size depending on the screen size. see [here](http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/handling-typography-responsive-design-4122794)